# Secret storage in JupyterHub or Helm? (Running on kubernetes on AWS EKS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, kubernetes-helm

I have JupyterHub running on a kubernetes cluster in AWS EKS (managed kubernetes on AWS).

I need to know if there is any way for me to store or configure a sensitive secret that can be accessed during a notebook server instance startup, but only by the server processes. It should never be accessible by any normal users or malicious users.

Specifically, I have a custom "postStart" step, configured in my helm chart:

```
proxy:
  # ...

auth
  # ...

singleuser:
  image:
    # ...
  lifecycleHooks:
    postStart:
      exec:
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "custom-program -password abcdefg12345"] # <-- THIS.
```

How can I safely store my password, e.g. `abcdefg12345` above, so that it can **never** be accessible to any users of the JupyterHub cluster? (Except admins)

Would it be safe in the helm chart config file? Where does helm store the postStart lifecycleHook command?

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes has the concept of [`Secrets`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) and allows to configure [role-based access control](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) (RBAC) for these. For the `Pod` running your server you need to create a [`ServiceAccount`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#service-account-permissions).